# Count number of times a particular value follows another particular value for each column in a data frame

Tags: r, count, sequence

I would like to create a table or a new data frame that displays, for each row in the original data frame, how many times a specific value precedes another specific value. For example, if I have the following data frame:

```
x <- data.frame("Red" = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d"), "Blue" = c("b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"), "Green" = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"))
```

and I want to know, for each color (Red, Blue, and Green) how many times the sequence "b", "a" occurs (i.e., how many times b precedes a in the sequence).

The correct answer would look something like this:

```
     Color ba
1   Red  1
2  Blue  3
3 Green  2
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one solution using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

count_pair <- function(x, pattern) {
   p <- paste(pattern, collapse = "")
   s <- paste(x, collapse = "")
   str_count(s, pattern = p)
}

z <- apply(x, 2, count_pair, pattern = c("b", "a"))
# Red  Blue Green 
# 1     3     2 

# if you want the output in form of a data.frame you could run:
df <- as.data.frame(as.table(z))

#    Var1 Freq
# 1   Red    1
# 2  Blue    3
# 3 Green    2
```

Comment: That should be `str_count(s, pattern = p)` in the last line of the function

Comment: true, i added the pattern argument afterwards and forgot that part. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! This worked great, but is there a way to get the output as a data frame or a table?